# Proper way to search through line of text, re.findall() and re.search() both don't fully work

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My question is a little odd, maybe someone can provide some guidance. I have a line of text that I need to search through and pull out multiple recurring strings to populate a dataframe. Given the following line:

`txt = "Name : 'red' Wire : 'R' Name : 'blue' Wire: 'B' Name : 'orange' Name: 'yellow' Wire : 'Y'"`

I want to regex through and pull out **ONLY** complete Name/Wire pairs (in this example not `Orange`).

expected output

```
Name    Wire
red      R
blue     B
yellow   Y
```

Code

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    a = re.search(r' Name : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
    if a:
        b = re.search(r' Wire : \'((?:(?![(]).)*)\'', line)
        if b:
            df = df.append({'Name' : a.group(1), 'Wire' : b.group(1)}, ignore_index=True)
```

This code produces the following df:

```
Name    Wire
red      R
```

This behavior is expected, as `re.search()` only runs until it finds the item in question the first time.

OK, `re.search()` wont work, so I will try `re.findall()` instead:

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    a = re.findall(r' Name : \"((?:(?![(]).)*)\"', line)
    if a:
        b = re.findall(r' Wire : \"((?:(?![(]).)*)\"', line)
        if b:
            df = df.append({'Name' : a, 'Wire' : b}, ignore_index=True)
```

This will spit out the following df:

```
Name                                    Wire
['red','blue','orange','yellow']        ['R','B','Y']
```

The issue with this dataframe is that now we no longer know what `Name` is associated with what `Wire`. Is there any way to have re.search() continue even after the first hit if it hasn't reached the end of the txt line? Anyone have any creative ideas on how to regex the line of text for only elements that contain everything(i.e. 'Name' **AND** 'Wire)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) function and specific regex pattern:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

txt = "Name : 'red' Wire : 'R' Name : 'blue' Wire: 'B' Name : 'orange' Name: 'yellow' Wire : 'Y'"
pat = re.compile(r"Name\s*:\s*'(?P<Name>[^']+)'\s+Wire\s*:\s*'(?P<Wire>[^']+)'")
items = [m.groupdict() for m in pat.finditer(txt)]
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
print(df)
```

- `(?P<Name>[^']+)` - *named subgroup* which is "translated" to [`m.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) object

The output:

```
    Name Wire
0     red    R
1    blue    B
2  yellow    Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to `pandas` but I achieved that with a list comprehension, maybe will be helpful to you:

```py
import re

def populateNameWire(content):
    pairs = re.findall(r'Name *: *\'(?P<name>\w+)\' Wire *: *\'(?P<wire>\w+)\'', content)
    return [{'Name': name, 'Wire': wire} for name, wire in pairs]
```

```py
populateNameWire("Name : 'red' Wire : 'R' Name : 'blue' Wire: 'B' Name : 'orange' Name: 'yellow' Wire : 'Y'")`
```

```
[{'Name': 'red', 'Wire': 'R'}, {'Name': 'blue', 'Wire': 'B'}, {'Name': 'yellow', 'Wire': 'Y'}]
```