# Regex through line of text with changing pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Expanding on [Proper way to search through line of text, re.findall() and re.search() both don't fully work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169867/proper-way-to-search-through-line-of-text-re-findall-and-re-search-both-don)

If I have the following line of text:

`txt = "Name : 'red' Wire : 'R' Wire: 'B' Name : 'blue' Name : 'orange' Name: 'yellow' Wire : 'Y'"`

I am trying to parse through this line of text and get every `Wire/Name` pair to populate into a dataframe. The issue with this text is that the order `Wire/Name` on the line of text is variable.

```
for line in txt:
    line = line.strip()
    pairs = re.findall(r'Name *: *\'(?P<name>\w+)\' Wire *: *\'(?P<wire>\w+)\'', content)
    if pairs:
        for name, wire in pairs:
            df = df.append({'Name' : name, 'Wire' : wire}, ignore_index=True)
```

The problem with this approach is that it misses the `Blue/B` pair, resulting in the following dataframe.

```
Name    Wire
red      R
yellow   Y
```

The dataframe I am trying to achieve is

```
Name    Wire
red      R
blue     B
yellow   Y
```

Is it possible to handle the variation in the text pattern?

Comment: Probably me but I'm struggling to see the exact rule here that could be applied... for instance, if you cater for blue by allowing the name/wire to be in opposite order, then potentially, you could end up with orange being Y?

Comment: @JonClements this is the hard part. I'm curious if it's even possible to handle both cases at the same time because of this.

Comment: It basically boils down to (simplifying the text for demonstration): `Name=Red Wire=R Wire=B Name=Yellow Wire=Y Name=Orange`... even if you extracted all names and wires separately then put 'em back together, it's going to get odd results. (You might get away with doing all the pairs that are in the correct order, but sorting out the remainder is going to be interesting or even not possible)

Comment: @JonClements yup I am starting to think its probably not going to be possible

Answer (score 1):

Can you just take one name/wire pair at a time and build up the pieces as you go? I created a Pair class with some helper functions:

```
txt = "Name : 'red' Wire : 'R' Wire: 'B' Name : 'blue' Name : 'orange' Name: 'yellow' Wire : 'Y'"
regex = r'((?P<name>Name)|(?P<wire>Wire))\s*?:\s*?\'(?P<value>\w+\')'
pat = re.compile(regex)

class Pair:
    name = ''
    wire = ''

    def populated(self):
        return self.name and self.wire

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(name=self.name, wire=self.wire)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.wire}'


current_pair = Pair()
all_pairs = []

for x in pat.finditer(txt):
    if x.group('name'):
        current_pair.name = x.group('value')
    elif x.group('wire'):
        current_pair.wire = x.group('value')

    if current_pair.populated():
        all_pairs.append(current_pair)
        current_pair = Pair()

for p in all_pairs:
    print(p)
```

You could alter this code to keep track of the incomplete pairs (i.e. 'orange') and decide what to do with those later.